# Quadric surface graphing applet

Tags: graphing-functions, applications, surfaces

Does anybody know of any online tool/applet that can be used to graph quadric surfaces? i.e. If I want an elliptic paraboloid, I can click on "elliptic paraboloid" and enter my own specified values for a, b, and c. I couldn't find one on google, any ideas?

Comment: I was sure I'd hit reject on that edit. I also don't think there is any need for a tag about java applets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [POV-Ray](http://www.povray.org/) 3D renderer can render [quadric surfaces](http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.1/299/), as well as [plenty of others](http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.1/273/).  It's not an applet, and it may not be quite as easy to use at first as you envision, but [the results](http://www.geometrie.tuwien.ac.at/vis/) can certainly be pretty.

Comment: Thanks, that's good enough for me!